# Optimization of function on interval

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a quantity that I want to maximize:
$$Q(x) = -(1-\alpha x)\ln(1-\alpha x) - \alpha x\ln(\alpha x)$$

If I just set the derivative to zero, I get $$x = \frac{1}{2\alpha}$$

which is almost fine. Unfortunately, both $x \in [0, 1]$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, so if $\alpha < 1/2$, I can't satisfy the equation for the extremal value. So I am wondering how to go about finding the maximal value of Q given that $\alpha$ is fixed at some value less than 1/2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<\frac{1}{2\alpha}$, the function $Q(x)$ is monotone increasing. Hence, if $1/2a>1$, then $Q(x)$ is increasing over the entire domain of $x$ and the optimum of $Q(x)$ will be attained at $x=1$.

---

By the way: $0$ cannot be in the domain of $x$, since $\ln(\alpha x)$ is not defined for $x=0$.